# ORA-06550 ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

I got this error when I am trying to execute this SQL expression in Oracle APEX 5.1

```
select A.ENTREPRISE_RET
from A
inner join B 
on A.ID_RET = B.ID_RETRAIT;
```

[image]

Comment: Your query looks fine syntactically, it may be possible that you missed out some selecting some part while executing it. How you are executing it?

Comment: I'm trying to get "ENTREPRISE_RET" to display in "SOUMISSIONNAIRE_RETENUE" in a form. the source of SOUMISSIONNAIRE_RETENUE is the SQL expression (above) instead of Database column,

Comment: Not sure I understand the scenario (I don't use Apex), but perhaps you are not supposed to have the semicolon on the end of the statement? (That can cause ORA-00911 or ORA-00933 in other places, so maybe this is a new variant i haven't seen before *8-)

Comment: Or if it's expecting an expression rather than a query, perhaps you need to enclose it in parentheses - `(select A.ENTREPRISE_RET from ...)`, again without the semicolon? I'm just guessing, clearly... You might have further issues anyway as it looks like this will return multiple values, as Littlefoot mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is not a "PL/SQL Expression", but (probably) "**SQL query (return single value)**".

Though, are you sure that this query returns just one value? There's no `WHERE` clause in your query, and you can't put many rows into a single item.

Or, should I correct myself: you can, if you use "SQL query (return colon separated values)" source type. No problem in doing that - you'd use `LISTAGG`, for example, but the question is whether that's what you really want.